# I have solved the GROUP ANAGRAM question in leetcode in two ways.Why one of them is not giving correct result whereas the other one is returing null?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, hashmap

Given an array of strings strs, group the anagrams together. You can return the answer in any order.

Solution 1:the correct one:

```
public List<List<String>> groupAnagrams(String[] strs) {
        HashMap<String,List<String>> hm=new HashMap<>();   
        
        for(String st:strs){
            char[] arr=st.toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(arr);
            String cannonical=new String(arr);
            if(!hm.containsKey(cannonical)){
                hm.put(cannonical,new LinkedList<String>());
            }
            
            hm.get(cannonical).add(st);
        }
       
        return new LinkedList<>(hm.values());
    }
```

Solution 2:Incorrect :

```
public List<List<String>> groupAnagrams(String[] strs) {
        HashMap<String,List<String>> hm=new HashMap<>();   
        
        for(String st:strs){
            char[] arr=st.toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(arr);
            String cannonical=new String(arr);
            
             hm.getOrDefault(cannonical,new LinkedList<String>()).add(st);
            
        }
        return new LinkedList<>(hm.values());
    }
```

why soln 2 is not working when both the codes are very similar

Comment: "I have solved ... one is not giving correct result. [...] Solution 2: Incorrect": just about terminology: a "solution", solves. If it doesn't produce correct results, it is not a solution.

Comment: Well, "similar" is pretty broad term. I would recommend starting by reading the documentation of the getOrDefault method: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault(java.lang.Object,V) - The documentation says nothing about that this method will modify the map and add the key with the default value if it isn't in the map yet.

Answer (score 1):

In Solution 1, when you create a new entry in the HashMap using `hm.put(cannonical,new LinkedList<String>())` , you ensure that if the `cannonical` key doesn't exist in the HashMap, a new LinkedList is created and associated with that key.

This way, when you later call `hm.get(cannonical).add(st)`, you are sure that there is a List associated with the `cannonical` key, and you **can safely add the current string `st` to that list**.

In Solution 2, the incorrect part is here:

```java
hm.getOrDefault(cannonical, new LinkedList<String>()).add(st);
```

The `getOrDefault` method will return either the existing list associated with the `cannonical` key or the newly created list, but this newly created list is never actually put into the HashMap. So, even though you correctly retrieve the list, **you're modifying a list that's not associated with any key in the HashMap**.

The correct version would be:

```java
hm.putIfAbsent(cannonical, new LinkedList<String>());
hm.get(cannonical).add(st);
```

Here, `putIfAbsent` ensures that a list is associated with the `cannonical` key, and then **you can safely add the current string to that list**.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem.

```
 hm.getOrDefault(cannonical,new LinkedList<String>()).add(st);
```

There is no key so you are trying to add a value to a list that isn't mapped.

Replace it with

```
hm.computeIfAbsent(cannonical, v-> new LinkedList<>()).add(st);
```

The above says, if `cannonical` is not present, create a value for it, and return that value, in this case a list.  Then you can add the string to the list.
`